# Safer & simpler allocation functions and macros

Tags: c, memory-management, posix, gcc

I wrote a bunch of functions and macros for safer and simpler allocation.  They are documented in their files.

---

Disclaimer:

The library requires POSIX extensions, GCC extensions, and LIBBSD extensions, but if someone wants to make it portable, it shouldn't be difficult to get rid of the extensions I used. But to me, they are of great help and make my life much easier.

I use `goto` because it is cleaner to me (the way I use it), but if someone wants to get rid of it, it should be easy.

I acknowledge some inconsistency in the parameter `nmemb` which is sometimes `ptrdiff_t` and some others `size_t`.  I would like it to always be `ptrdiff_t`, but in the macros that call standard functions (instead of mine) those standard functions accept `size_t`, and the code to reject negative values of `ptrdiff_t` inside a macro would make the macros too long and dangerous.  In functions and in macros that call functions of mine, I consistently use `ptrdiff_t`.

---

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/README.rst`:

```
<libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/>
============================

The following functions are added to the C / POSIX / GNU / BSD allocation
functions (some of them may be implemented as macros; only when necessary).


1) Headers
----------

.. code-block:: c

        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarrays.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarrays.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocs.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocs.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayfs.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayfs.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrays.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrays.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocfs.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocfs.hpp>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.h>
        <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.hpp>

2) Functions
------------

.. code-block:: c

        [[gnu::nonnull]]
        int     callocs(type **restrict ptr, size_t nmemb);

        [[gnu::malloc]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        void    *mallocarray(ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);

        [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     mallocarrays(type **restrict ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb);

        [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     mallocs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);

        [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        void    *reallocarrayf(void *ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);

        [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     reallocarrayfs(type **restrict ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb);

        [[gnu::nonnull]][[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     reallocarrays(type **restrict ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb);

        [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     reallocfs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);

        [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
        int     reallocs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);

To be able to use any of those functions, the corresponding headers should be
included.

3) When to use each of the functions
------------------------------------

Functions ending in ``s`` should always be preferred.

Reallocation functions ending in ``f`` (or ``fs``) free the memory upon
failure to ease error handling.

Functions containing ``array`` (and ``callocs()``) should be used when
allocating arrays, or single elements (arrays of size 1).  The other funtions
should be used when and only when dealing with buffers of bytes.

4) More info
------------

For more detailed documentation about each of the functions, read the
corresponding headers.
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]]
 * int  callocs(type **restrict ptr, size_t nmemb);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `calloc()`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - Safely computes the element size (second argument to `calloc()`)
 *      so the user can't make mistakes.
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              if (callocs(&arr, 7))           // int arr[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * callocs()
 *
 * ptr:         Memory will be allocated, and a pointer to it will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
#define alx_callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                                       \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        *ptr_   = calloc(nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));                        \
                                                                        \
        !(*ptr_);                                                       \
}                                                                       \
)


/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb)     alx_callocs(ptr, nmemb)
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::malloc]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * void *mallocarray(ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);
 *
 * Almost equivalent to `reallocarray(NULL, nmemb, size)`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - It fails safely if (nmemb < 0).  With `reallocarray()` the array would be
 *      be allocated (it uses `size_t` instead of `ptrdiff_t`), and it's usage
 *      would likely produce undefined behavior.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              arr     = mallocarray(7, sizeof(*arr));         // int arr[7];
 *              if (!arr)
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * mallocarray()
 *
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 * size:        Size of each element in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      != NULL:        OK.
 *      NULL:           Failed.
 */
__attribute__((malloc, warn_unused_result))
inline
void    *alx_mallocarray        (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, malloc, warn_unused_result))
static inline
void    *mallocarray            (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_mallocarray(nmemb, size);
}
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
inline
void    *alx_mallocarray        (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{

        if (nmemb < 0)
                goto ovf;

        return  reallocarray(NULL, nmemb, size);
ovf:
        errno   = ENOMEM;
        return  NULL;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarrays.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarrays.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  mallocarrays(type **restrict ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `mallocarray()`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - Safely computes the element size (second argument to `mallocarray()`)
 *      so the user can't make mistakes.
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarrays.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              if (mallocarrays(&arr, 7))              // int arr[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h"


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * mallocarrays()
 *
 * ptr:         Memory will be allocated, and a pointer to it will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
#define alx_mallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)    (                               \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        *ptr_   = alx_mallocarray(nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));               \
                                                                        \
        !(*ptr_);                                                       \
}                                                                       \
)


/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
#define mallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)        alx_mallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* function prototypes **************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline functions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocs.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocs.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]]  [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  mallocs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `malloc()`.
 * To be used for generic buffers of bytes, and not for arrays (use
 * `mallocarray()` family of functions for that purpose).
 *
 * Features:
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocs.h>
 *
 *              char *buf;
 *
 *              if (mallocs(&buf, 7))           // char buf[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `buf` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(buf);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * mallocs()
 *
 * ptr:         Memory will be allocated, and a pointer to it will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * size:        Size of the buffer (in bytes).
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     alx_mallocs     (void **restrict ptr, size_t size);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, nonnull, warn_unused_result))
static inline
int     mallocs         (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_mallocs(ptr, size);
}
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
inline
int     alx_mallocs     (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{

        *ptr    = malloc(size);

        return  !(*ptr);
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * void *reallocarrayf(void *ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);
 *
 * Almost equivalent to `reallocarray()`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - Upon failure, the passed pointer is freed, to ease error handling and to
 *      avoid memory leaks.
 * - It fails safely if (nmemb < 0).  With `reallocarray()` the array would be
 *      be allocated (it uses `size_t` instead of `ptrdiff_t`), and it's usage
 *      would likely produce undefined behavior.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              arr     = mallocarray(5, sizeof(*arr);          // int arr[5];
 *              arr     = reallocarrayf(arr, 7, sizeof(*arr));  // int arr[7];
 *              if (!arr)
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully reallocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* _Static_assert *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
_Static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(ptrdiff_t),
                                "sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(ptrdiff_t)");


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * reallocarrayf()
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to allocated memory (or NULL).
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 * size:        Size of each element in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      != NULL:        OK.
 *      NULL:           Failed.
 */
__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
inline
void    *alx_reallocarrayf      (void *ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, warn_unused_result))
static inline
void    *reallocarrayf          (void *ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_reallocarrayf(ptr, nmemb, size);
}
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
inline
void    *alx_reallocarrayf      (void *ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{

        if (!size)
                goto out;
        if (nmemb < 0)
                goto ovf;
        if ((size_t)nmemb  >  (SIZE_MAX / size))
                goto ovf;

        return  reallocf(ptr, size * (size_t)nmemb);
ovf:
        errno   = ENOMEM;
out:
        free(ptr);
        return  NULL;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayfs.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayfs.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  reallocarrayfs(type **restrict ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `reallocarrayf()`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - Safely computes the element size (second argument to `reallocarrayf()`)
 *      so the user can't make mistakes.
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast.
 * - Upon failure, the passed pointer is freed, to ease error handling and to
 *      avoid memory leaks.
 * - It fails safely if (nmemb < 0).  With `reallocarray()` the array would be
 *      be allocated (it uses `size_t` instead of `ptrdiff_t`), and it's usage
 *      would likely produce undefined behavior.
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayfs.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              if (mallocarrays(&arr, 5))      // int arr[5];
 *                      goto err;
 *              if (reallocarrayfs(&arr, 7))    // int arr[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully reallocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include "libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrayf.h"


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * reallocarrayfs()
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to a pointer to the memory to be reallocated.
 *              A pointer to the reallocated memory will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
#define alx_reallocarrayfs(ptr, nmemb)  (                               \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        *ptr_   = alx_reallocarrayf(*ptr_, nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));      \
                                                                        \
        !(*ptr_);                                                       \
}                                                                       \
)


/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
#define reallocarrayfs(ptr, nmemb)      alx_reallocarrayfs(ptr, nmemb)
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* function prototypes **************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline functions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrays.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrays.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]][[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  reallocarrays(type **restrict ptr, size_t nmemb);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `reallocarray()`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - Safely computes the element size (second argument to `reallocarray()`)
 *      so the user can't make mistakes.
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast.
 * - Upon failure, the pointer is untouched (no memory leak).
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocarrays.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              if (mallocarrays(&arr, 5))      // int arr[5];
 *                      goto err;
 *              if (reallocarrays(&arr, 7))     // int arr[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully reallocated here
 *      err:
 *              free(arr);
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.h"


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * reallocarrays()
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to a pointer to the memory to be reallocated.
 *              A pointer to the reallocated memory will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
#define alx_reallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)   (                               \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
        __auto_type     nmemb_  = (nmemb);                              \
        void            *vp_;                                           \
                                                                        \
        vp_     = reallocarray(*ptr_, nmemb_, sizeof(**ptr_));          \
                                                                        \
        alx_reallocs__(ptr_, vp_, nmemb_);                              \
}                                                                       \
)


/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
#define reallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)       alx_reallocarrays(ptr, nmemb)
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* function prototypes **************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline functions *****************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocfs.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocfs.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  reallocfs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `reallocf()`.
 * To be used for generic buffers of bytes, and not for arrays (use
 * `reallocarray()` family of functions for that purpose).
 *
 * Features:
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast.
 * - Upon failure, the passed pointer is freed, to ease error handling and to
 *      avoid memory leaks.
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocfs.h>
 *
 *              char *buf;
 *
 *              if (mallocs(&buf, 5))   // char buf[5];
 *                      goto err;
 *              if (reallocfs(&buf, 7)) // char buf[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `buf` has been succesfully reallocated here
 *              free(buf);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * reallocfs()
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to a pointer to the memory to be reallocated.
 *              A pointer to the reallocated memory will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * size:        Size of the buffer (in bytes).
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     alx_reallocfs   (void **restrict ptr, size_t size);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, nonnull, warn_unused_result))
static inline
int     reallocfs       (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_reallocfs(ptr, size);
}
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
inline
int     alx_reallocfs   (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{

        *ptr    = reallocf(*ptr, size);

        return  !*ptr;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

`libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.h`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.h */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* about ****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * [[gnu::nonnull]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * int  reallocs(void **restrict ptr, size_t size);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `reallocf()`.
 * To be used for generic buffers of bytes, and not for arrays (use
 * `reallocarray()` family of functions for that purpose).
 *
 * Features:
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast.
 * - Upon failure, the pointer is untouched (no memory leak).
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/reallocs.h>
 *
 *              char *buf;
 *
 *              if (mallocs(&buf, 5))   // char buf[5];
 *                      goto err;
 *              if (reallocs(&buf, 7))  // char buf[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `buf` has been succesfully reallocated here
 *      err:
 *              free(buf);
 *              // No memory leaks
 */


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* enum *****************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* struct / union *******************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************
 ******* prototypes ***********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * reallocs()
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to a pointer to the memory to be reallocated.
 *              A pointer to the reallocated memory will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * size:        Size of the buffer (in bytes).
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Failed.
 */
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     alx_reallocs    (void **restrict ptr, size_t size);

/*
 * alx_reallocs__()
 *
 * This function safely assigns the result of a reallocation to the pointer
 * provided.  If the reallocation failed, this function doesn't assign the
 * pointer, and keeps the old one.  This function is only to be used within
 * this library, and should not be called directly by the user.
 *
 * ptr:         Pointer to a pointer to the memory to be reallocated.
 *              A pointer to the reallocated memory will be stored
 *              in *ptr.
 * vp:          Result of `realloc()`.
 * size:        `size` passed to `realloc()`.
 *
 * return:
 *      0:              OK.
 *      != 0:           Reallocation failed.
 */
__attribute__((nonnull(1), warn_unused_result))
inline
int     alx_reallocs__  (void **restrict ptr, void *restrict vp, size_t size);


/******************************************************************************
 ******* static inline ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Rename without alx_ prefix */
#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, nonnull, warn_unused_result))
static inline
int     reallocs        (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_reallocs(ptr, size);
}
#endif


/******************************************************************************
 ******* inline ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
inline
int     alx_reallocs    (void **restrict ptr, size_t size)
{
        void    *vp;

        vp      = realloc(*ptr, size);

        return  alx_reallocs__(ptr, vp, size);
}

inline
int     alx_reallocs__  (void **restrict ptr, void *restrict vp, size_t size)
{
        bool    failed;

        failed  = !vp && size;
        if (!failed)
                *ptr    = vp;

        return  failed;
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******* end of file **********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

Any comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Doxygen to document your code

It's already mentioned by others, but you have a lot of comments. It's good to document all the functions, but you are not using a standard code documentation language as far as I can tell. I recomment that you use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). The advantage is that it understands C and C++, and will perform checks on your documentation, such as that you documented all the parameters and the return value. Furthermore, it allows the creation of a manual in PDF and HTML formats (amongs others), which are much nicer for a developer to read than having to read the source files.

## Avoid (complex) macros

It's always better to use functions than macros. If you cannot avoid macros, for example to allow arbitrary type arguments to be passed, it is better to create a simple macro to deal with the parameter type, and then call a regular function to do the main work. For example:

```
static inline int alx_callocs_impl(void **ptr, size_t nmemb, size_t size) {
    *ptr = calloc(nmemb, size);
    return !*ptr;
}

#define alx_callocs(ptr, nmemb) alx_callocs_impl((ptr), (nmemb), sizeof(ptr))
```

## About the disclaimers

> The library requires POSIX extensions, GCC extensions, and LIBBSD extensions

That's a lot of requirements for such a low-level library, making it much less useful. Even if this library is only for your personal use, consider that in the future you might want to port your projects to platforms that don't support POSIX, libbsd or GCC.

> I use goto because it is cleaner to me (the way I use it)

I think a lot of these uses of `goto` are unnecessary. For example, you can rewrite `alx_mallocarray()` like this:

```
inline void *alx_mallocarray(ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size) {
    if (nmemb < 0) {
        errno = ENOMEM
        return NULL;
    }

    return reallocarray(NULL, nmemb, size);
}
```

> I acknowledge some inconsistency in the parameter nmemb which is sometimes ptrdiff_t and some others size_t. I would like it to always be ptrdiff_t, but in the macros that call standard functions (instead of mine) those standard functions accept size_t, and the code to reject negative values of ptrdiff_t inside a macro would make the macros too long and dangerous. In functions and in macros that call functions of mine, I consistently use ptrdiff_t.

There is a reason that standard library and POSIX functions use unsigned types like `size_t` sometimes, and signed types like `int` or `ssize_t` at other times, and there is a consistency to it. When a parameter should never be a negative number, `size_t` is used. Doing so will make it easier to catch errors; and avoids you having to write checks like `if (nmemb < 0)`.

Another reason not to use different parameter types than those used by standard library functions is that it goes against users' expectations.

Comment: There are good reasons to use `ptrdiff_t`.  I'm searching for an article I read a long time ago, but while I find it, I can link you to this one, which isn't as extense, but is also good (it is C++, but it's meaningful in C too): https://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf

Comment: *"Avoid (complex) macros"*: Good solution :)

Comment: Some words from Bjarne Stroustrup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Puio5dly9N8&t=42m41s

And from Google's C++ Coding Style: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types

Comment: "There is a reason the standard functions use `size_t` sometimes, and `ssize_t` at other times" --> There a no standard C library function that uses `ssize_t` as `ssize_t` is not in the C spec.  The point of the paragraph based on a false premise.  OP's code used `ptrdiff_t` for `nmemb`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct for the standard library. I was thinking about POSIX functions like `read()` that return `ssize_t`. I updated the answer. I don't know of any standard library or POSIX function that takes a `ptrdiff_t` argument or returns a `ptrdiff_t`; it's either `int` or `ssize_t`. C99's `calloc()` and `reallocarray()` functions use `size_t nmemb`, so that's why I pointed out it might be confusing to wrap those functions but use different argument types.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with lots of comments such as these in header files, that's just your personal opinion. Doxygen doesn't really produce any complete, sensible documentation, it's just a way of writing glorified source code comments. When coding, I don't want to get handed some f-in auto-generated pdf that doesn't say more than what was written in the comments anyway. I either want brief source code comments or complete documentation written in detail, with rationales and explanations about the implementation etc.

Comment: @Lundin: nobody wants bad documentation. And Doxygen is not going to magically make good documentation. But the point is that if you are documenting each function, then it's good to use a standard way of doing that, so that you can use tools that help you with that.

Answer (score 5):

### Portability

While `#pragma once` is widely supported it is not part of the C programming standard. To make this library more portable, use include guards such as shown in the example below.

### Ease of Use

Don't force the users of the library to include files in the proper order, functions that are written using other functions in the library need to include the header for the other function. There is no guarantee that the user of the library wants to include one header file that includes all the other header files.

### Useless Comments

In the comments after another answer there is a statement that the is 47 KLOC (K lines of code). Comments don't count as lines of code and it appears that each file is about 70% comments. I agree with the author of the other answer that this could all be in a single file.

There are a lot of boiler plate comments that are not useful, comments such as `include guard` really don't help anyone. The `About` comments don't need a header comment and should include the comment block that describes the entry point, here is one example:

```
#ifndef MALLOCARRAY_H
#define MALLOCARRAY_H
/*
 *  About:
 * [[gnu::malloc]] [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
 * void *mallocarray(ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);
 *
 * Almost equivalent to `reallocarray(NULL, nmemb, size)`.
 *
 * Features:
 * - It fails safely if (nmemb < 0).  With `reallocarray()` the array would be
 *      be allocated (it uses `size_t` instead of `ptrdiff_t`), and it's usage
 *      would likely produce undefined behavior.
 *
 * example:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/mallocarray.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              arr     = mallocarray(7, sizeof(*arr));         // int arr[7];
 *              if (!arr)
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 *
 * Parameters:
 * nmemb:       Number of elements in the array.
 * size:        Size of each element in the array.
 *
 * return:
 *      != NULL:        OK.
 *      NULL:           Failed.
*/

#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "reallocArray.h"
__attribute__((malloc, warn_unused_result))
inline
void    *alx_mallocarray        (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size);

#if defined(ALX_NO_PREFIX)
__attribute__((always_inline, malloc, warn_unused_result))
static inline
void    *mallocarray            (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
        return  alx_mallocarray(nmemb, size);
}
#endif

inline
void    *alx_mallocarray        (ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{

    if (nmemb < 0)
        goto ovf;

    return  reallocarray(NULL, nmemb, size);
    ovf:
    errno   = ENOMEM;
    return  NULL;
}

#endif // MALLOCARRAY_H
```

### Opinionated Summary

It is not clear who would benefit from this library, the C programming language has been around for almost 50 years. If a library like this was beneficial it would have been written before this.

Comment: *"Portability"*:  I've had many issues with header guards (more than once I forgot to change the name after copy&paste), and as you said, `#pragma once` is implemented by [most compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23696115/6872717).  Even MSVC has that.

Comment: *"Ease of use"*: All of my headers include internally all they need.  There's no proper order, and you can include any of the headers separately and it will work.  If some header (or some source) needs some other header it will be included so the user doesn't have to care.

Comment: *"Useless comments"*:  Although there are a lot of comments in these files, the rest of the library is mostly uncommented (yet).  While I don't have a program to count LOC without comments or blank lines, I guess there will be at least 15 kLOC, which is still too much, and there are also C and C++ files, and although it would probably be possible to have a C header + a C++ header + a C source + a C++ source, it would be much more difficult to maintain such huge files.

Comment: *"Opinionated Summary"*:  I do benefit from this library.  It makes my programs much shorter and easier to write and I hope someone might want to use it too, although I don't need that.  There are many programs out there that have bugs still waiting to bite because the standard library is sometimes difficult to use safely (for example `strtol()` or `realloc()`).  And even if someone knows how to use them safely, that means writing the same 4 or 5 lines for every `realloc()` call, while with this library I wrote them once and forgot about them.

Comment: `more than once I forgot to change the name after copy&paste` It's obvious you use copy and paste which in and of itself is a rather bad programming practice.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause, but rather the symptom:  The cause is having to write almost the same thing for every file.  The cure: pragma once.   With `realloc()` it's also the same:  You have to take the element size & check that you don't overflow the multiplication & check that the function didn't fail before updating the pointer;  in the end you have to write almost the same code for every call, and you either write a function/macro for not repeating yourself or copy&paste every time or write the same code every time.  Again copy&paste is not bad in itself, but rather a symptom.  IMHO.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito If you don't want to accept a review, don't request one.

Comment: @JL2210 It's not that I don't accept it.  It's just that I feel a part of it is wrong (I think that the part of the include order is because he didn't understand that I don't require that; which may be a problem of mine becuase I should have explained that),  and for the other part, I partially disagree, but give my reasons for that, so that he can give me counter arguments and maybe make me change my mind (it wouldn't be the first time). :)

Comment: You want to look at the third answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards. No experienced professional programmer enjoys fixing copy and paste and they will refactor it if they are allowed to because copy and paste code generally creates bugs, your experience with #include guards is just one example. Object Oriented Design and Programming and inheritance is/was in part an effort to reduce copy & paste errors. Writing a function for each memory allocation is effectively implementing the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: One way to see how much code is comments and macros is to run the c pre-processor on the code and then look at the resulting c code. If you have any more comments ping me on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want people to use your library, then you want to think about how to make it easy for others to adopt it.

I would consider revamping the implementation into a [Single-file library](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs). Simply put, the more files, the more tedious it becomes to add someone else's code to your project. Which is why, single-file libraries are popular in the C/C++ world because they are easy to manage (package management facilities are lacking in these languages). Personally, I've used hashmaps, bignum libraries, red-black trees etc, all delivered as single-file C libraries. But if I have to add more than one (or two) files to use someone else's code, likely I won't bother.

For me, the other dealbreaker would be Windows compatiblity. Windows compatiblity is very important for me and I can see that you are using several features not available on MSVC.

Comment: I would like to add Windows (x64) compatibility in the future, but that's something I may need help and time; mainly because I don't use Windows.

Comment: For the single-file library: My library currently has over 47 k lines of code, so I don't see it fitting in one header & one source. What I did some time ago was to have a dummy header <libalx.h> to include all of the headers, but as I did it when I started writing the library, I realized that I had to continuously update that file and sometimes I forgot it. However, when I release the first stable version of the library, I could do that; it's a nice addition. I still prefer to include each header, because then I know where to go for documentation, but I can see the benefit of having that. :)

Comment: The idea I have for this library is to install it in the system (via apt-get or similar) and use it just by including the headers.  That way, I ease the installation part.  The separation into tiny files helps me organize and maintain the code and easily find a function.  But then if I have a dummy header to include them all, the user could also be happy by ignoring the details of the library.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito So these allocation functions are just one part of a much larger "libalx" library containing lots of other utility routines?

Comment: Exactly. It's a big library where I put all the code I repeatedly use.